# Positive lookbehind and Safari workaround

Tags: javascript, regex, safari

so i have a file of lines like so....

```
valueA +920.32 % valueA +479.89%
valueB +886.82 % valueB +424.59%
--- insert more similar lines ---
```

And I was using the following Regex to get only the two percents and store them in an array

```
myObject.valueA = text.match(/(?<=valueA)(?:.+?(?=%))/g);
```

resulting in which is what I desire

```
valueA: Array [ " +920.32 ", " +479.89" ]
```

I was very happy with that, and keep moving forward with my little project until I was trying to test it with my friend on an iPhone, and nothing happened. Which I have found out is due to safari not supporting positive look behinds so I have been looking for something to produced a similar result.

With a positive look ahead I got close but it included 'valueA ' in the result which i really don't want to have to remove with an extra line of code.

```
(?=valueA)(?:.+?(?=%))
```

Result

```
valueA: Array [ "valueA +920.32 ", "valueA +479.89" ]
```

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but I've been messing around on RegExr and had no luck.  Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Use capture groups: `/valueA\s+(\S+)\s+%/`

Comment: That still includes 'valueA' itself which is the same issue i have with a positive lookahead

Comment: When you grab 1st capture group it will have just `+920.32`

Comment: ah sorry! I see that now, but it doesn't seem to grab both +920.32 and +479.89 which i am trying to accomplish. Unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Wrong dupe. Question is specific to Safari issue of lookbehind not supported instead of just finding test between 2 strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this workaround using capture groups in [`matchAll` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll):

```js
const s = `valueA +920.32 % valueA +479.89%
valueB +886.82 % valueB +424.59%`

var arr = [...s.matchAll(/\bvalueA\s+([^\s%]+)/g)]

arr.forEach(el => console.log( el[1] ))
```

Comment: almost perfect went from this...

    `myObject.valueA = text.match(/(?=valueA)(?:.+?(?=%))/g);`

to this
`myObject.valueA  = [...text.matchAll(/\valueA\s+([^\s%]+)/g)];
    myObject.valueA.forEach((el, i) => myObject.valueA[i]= el[1]);` Not one line anymore but better than my solution

Answer (score 1):

If thats really what the data looks like why not just capture +, ., and digits? `([\+\d\.]+)`

```js
const text = `valueA +920.32 % valueA +479.89%`;

console.log(text.match(/([\+\d\.]+)/g))
```

Comment: because the data will have several lines with 32 possible values. not every value will be included and they may not always be in the right order, so I can't just assume that the first two numbers go to valueA